# Force look and feel on NetBeans 6.5

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel

How do you for a specific look and feel on NetBeans 6.5? I mean by passing flags to the netbeans script (on Ubuntu) or by modifying the netbeans script or by some setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your netbeans.conf file, [add "--laf "](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomLaf) to your `netbeans_default_options` value.

Check out the [Netbeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/).

Note: [Netbeans Substance plug-in](http://wiki.netbeans.org/LookAndFeel) is no longer under development as of August 25, 2008.

Comment: I've ended up using the --laf argument, some interesting places to look at are: 
http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2008/05/netbeans-ide-look-and-feel.html
http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBLookAndFeels

By the wat, the NetBeans Substance plug in seems to be abandoned.