# Changing NetBeans UI Look/Feel

Tags: java, macos, swing, netbeans, interface

Is it possible to somehow change the look/feel of NetBeans? I know it uses Swing and that usually apps using Swing for its UI can usually have their UI scheme changed.

The default appearence for OSX is vomitastic and would even settle for just some sort of barebones `default` look. The whole look is just too distracting and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer to this question:
[Force look and feel on NetBeans 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231738/force-look-and-feel-on-netbeans-65#233855)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this might be what I was looking for:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomLaf

Answer (score 1):

**To change the default look and feel of netbeans 7.2.1 go to the home directory\Program file \netbeans 7.2.1\etc;**

Now open to the **netbeans.confg** file and find out the following text.

netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"

**Now add the following text**;

*-- laf com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel;*

**Now it will be looked like;**

netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true ***--laf com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"***

**//Now you can see the new look and feel of netbeans (NimbusLookAndFeel)**