# NetBeans GUI editor skin/theme

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, editor, themes, designer

I'm creating a Java Web Applet in NetBeans and I want my final application to have a design called *"Metal"*. I can set it, it's OK. But when I'm editing the GUI using *"NetBeans GUI editor"*, I must work with the typical Windows design. Is it possible to use the *"Metal"* skin in the editor too? Each design has different sizes of buttons, fonts etc. So I'd love to see the final layout during editing. Not only after compiling.

I know that I can right-click and select *"Design preview / Metal"* but I do not want this. 
For ilustration I'm attaching an image:

[image: NetBeans GUI editor appearance]

I saw this question in a few forums, but nobody understood it well (and nobody answered), so I'm asking my own question.

Comment: If you have got working answer you may always accept one of the answers which is more helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks, it worked. But `<snip>` caused an error message, so I added to

`"netbeans_default_options"` only this:

`"--laf javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel"`

Side effect was, that whole NetBeans now have Metal design. But I like it, so why not.

Comment: See my comment, I just wrote `snip` to say that there might be other parameters which I didn't quote in my answer to keep it short

Comment: @Racky: you should accept one of the answers that helped with clicking the green tick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring Netbeans to use the Metal look and feel by editing `netbeans.conf`.

```
netbeans_default_options="... --laf javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel"
```

**Note:** After a normal Netbeans installation there's already a `netbeans_default_options` setting in the configuration file. Be careful not delete them unless you know what you are doing. Just *append* the `--laf` option.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But <snip> caused an error message, so I added to "netbeans_default_options" only this: "--laf javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel". Side effect was, that whole NetBeans now have Metal design. But I like it, so why not.

Comment: The <snip> means that I cut away all the other options normally added to that line.

Answer (score 1):

1) This question was once answered at [Force look and feel on NetBeans 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231738/force-look-and-feel-on-netbeans-6-5) Please take a look there also.

2) Some years ago I have written a detailed tutorial for Look and Feel changes in NetBeans.  Please also have a look at http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2008/05/netbeans-ide-look-and-feel.html

with regards
Tushar Joshi, Nagpur