# How to add a .jar file to netbeans, not a reference

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

[image]
I downloaded a look and feel .jar to my desktop, then in netbeans added it to my libraries folder in my java project.
But it appears to just be a reference to the actual .jar on my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans doesn't care (and doesn't need) your jar. What you have to do is add the jar to your project, instead of adding an external library to netbeans.

If your project is a maven project (unlikely), add the jar as a dependency.

If your project is a java project then look for a library (lib) folder.

If you are trying to modify the look and feel of netbeans itself: [Force look and feel on NetBeans 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231738/force-look-and-feel-on-netbeans-6-5#233855)

Comment: i dont know if i was clear so i added a picture of my netbeans project, you can see the mouse over on the jtatoo jar, its pointing to my desktop not my project

Comment: If you added it as an "external library" then remove the link, find where the libraries folder is kept and move the jar into there, or create your own lib folder inside of your project, move the file to over there and add it to netbeans not as an external library.

Comment: awesome! it worked when i made a new lib folder... i dont understand why i had to do that but thanks!

Comment: i thought i could figure this out but i have a classnotfoundexception for this line: UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel"); i tried adding the source not no luck!

Comment: i'll just ask in a new question